# How to place a static block after another in "Before Main Columns"?

Tags: magento2, layout

I placed a Static Block (called `home_main_content`) using a Widget (sort order = 0) from Magento Backend like this:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to insert another Static Block which I created using my custom module. I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryList" template="Vendor_Module::cms.phtml" name="category_list" after="home_main_content" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

but it positions itself either before all on top of the main content or on the bottom of the main content.

How can I position my `category_list` right after the other one `home_main_content`?

Comment: did you try `referenceContainer name="content"` ?

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't work. How can I sort more blocks inside the same container? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your custom block "category_list" after widget then you just need to write below code in cms_index_index.xml file in your theme path app/design/frontend/PackageName/customtheme/Magento_Cms/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryList" template="Vendor_Module::cms.phtml" name="category_list" after="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

With the use of **after="-"** , it will show your custom block after widget element.

Cheers!